# Series Question (Sum to infinity) & Finding the smallest value

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help with part c) in the question shown in the image.

[Series Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9mJu.jpg)

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  When you edit the question, you should also show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} 162\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ can be simplified to $2^{k+1} \cdot 3^{5-k}$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}u_n=u_k\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^j=324\times (\frac{2}{3})^k=s_k$  Solve for $k$, from $s_k\le 2.5$, using logs.